# How to set transaction nonce when sending multiple transactions at the same time?

Tags: nonce, sendsignedtransaction

If I send transactions(web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction) to one contract at the same time using 10 different wallet addresses,do I need to manually set the nonce for each transaction? And how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `sendSignedTransaction` you actually just send the signed transaction so you don't need the nonce for that step, what you need the nonce for is to sign the transaction with `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey [, callback]);` where the nonce is actually an optional parameter, I would recommend do not set a specific nonce and just let the default kick in.

The default nonce will compute `web3.eth.getTransactionCount()` so it makes sure you are using the right nonce everytime.